# hangman game, syntax fix x86 gcc assembly & C

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, assembly, cpu-registers

My final project is a hangman game. The chosen word is picked randomly from a database.The user inputs a `char` via `scanf`, and then must be compared to the chosen word via assembly.Since `C` doesn't have a string var., a string is just an array of characters, SO the inputted `char` is in a `for loop` and must be compared to each indexed `char` in the array.

Now the assembly function is passed:int i (index #), char string1 pointer(array word), and char string2 pointer (user input).

```
movb    8(%ebp), %ecx   /*store i -> cx reg*/
movb    12(%ebp),%ebx   /*store *string1 -> bh reg*/
movb    16(%ebp),%edx   /*store (userinput)*string2 ->bl reg*/
movb    (%ebx,%ecx,1),%al
movb    (%ebx,%ecx,1), %ah
movl    $0,     %eax
cmpl    %al,    %ah
jne     end
movl    $1,     %eax
```

I know these 2 lines are incorrect syntax, I need to know how to properly offset these mov instructions. Also, if there are other errors too. This is supposed to compare the two registers after being offset. I'm new to assembly.

```
movb    (%bh,%cx,1),%edx
movb    (%bl,%cx,1), %eax
```

edit: So it's now only giving me a return of 1 when comparing the 2 chars, even if they're different.

Comment: It seems to me that you are moving two pointers to bh and bl, which are 8 bit registers. Is it intended?

Comment: well both pointers are char pointers, so that's 1byte=8bits, so I didn't think I needed more than that. As for if I can move it into a larger register, I'm wondering if that is valid, or there is a way to do that.

Comment: pointers have a different size then the object they refer to!!!!
You can look it up or find out with sizeof(char) and sizeof(char*).

Comment: okay, so what is the size for pointers?

Comment: depends on what machine you are on. As i said, write a simple c program which outputs sizeof(). I would definitely go for a full sized register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use 8-bit or 16-bit registers such as `%bh`, `%bl` and `%cx` as address and/or index registers in 32 bit mode.  You should use `%ecx`, `%ebx` and `%edx` as pointer and index registers, and use `%al` and `%ah` to load bytes from the strings:

```
movl    8(%ebp),%ecx    /* store 32 bit i -> ecx reg */
movl    12(%ebp),%ebx   /* store string1 -> ebx reg */
movl    16(%ebp),%edx   /* store (userinput) string2 -> edx */
movb    (%ebx,%ecx,1),%al
movb    (%edx,%ecx,1),%ah
cmpb    %al,%ah
jne     here
movl    $0,%eax
jmp     end
```

If `i` has type `unsigned char` on the C side, you must zero extend the 8 bit value this way:

```
movzbl  8(%ebp),%ecx    /* store 8 bit i -> ecx reg */
```

Comment: YES! Thank you. I did end up changing the registers to 32bit before I saw this, but I wasn't getting a correct return value until i tried using %al & %ah.

Comment: okay, so I jumped the gun. I'm actually only getting a return value of 1 now.

Comment: I edited the original post with what the code looks like now

Comment: @Riker: you are not supposed to do that.  It makes the discussion and answers inconsistent.  You should revert this edit.